# Unable to get angular 2 form validation to work

Tags: angular

I tried going through the bwlow tutorial to do form validation in angular 2 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

But it just returns a blank page.

However, if I replace the following line

```
<form *ngIf="active" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #heroForm="ngForm">
```

with

```
<form>
```

at least i get some form elements appearing. The difficult part is that there seems to be no error messages that can direct me to the problem.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the state of *active* variable? It must be true because you have used the ngIf:

```
<form *ngIf="active" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #heroForm="ngForm">
```

Everything seems to work fine, but your form is just not rendered because active is not present/is false.

Comment: The component class should contain - public active = true; to initialize ngIf. Its easy to miss because it is not mentioned in the reactive forms docs.